# Jboss step by step set hot deploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, netbeans-8

Hello i would like ask how it is possible configure jboss server for something like live, hot deploment:

- every time when i change some code of my jsp,html,js or css file i always need to clean and build project than deploy project to jboss and again, agian and again. That cost alot of my time. I waste time for that. It will be easy when i could work on files which already use a started jboss (deployed). But this files is in WAR file "project.war" and throught my IDE (Netbeans) i cant edit this files (jsp,css,html or js). Netbeans made this file uneditable.

[image]

I Would glad for solution step by step how it is possible to avoid this boring process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Edit Standalone.xml,change development to "true"
   `<configuration>
     <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
   </configuration>`
2. Start JBoss.
3. Go to ServerLocation-> standalone\tmp\vfs
4. Sort by "Date Modified" descending
5. Open the first folder(something like deployment*******)
6. There will be your complete exploded war.
7. Go to the jsps,js,css location,edit & save the changes.
8. changes will be displayed live.

Comment: i dont have in standalone.xml file, tag "<configuration>". When i try add than jboss dosent run. My jboss version jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Comment: so u mean i have to add to standalone.xml following code:  <subsystem>
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
            </configuration>
        </subsystem>

Comment: I am using wild fly 8.1.0 , but it is only works 2 or 3 times. after that I have to restart the server again.

Comment: change standalone.xml like this
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <configuration>
                <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
            </configuration>

Comment: You can search by tag "<jsp-config/>" into "stadalone.xml" file. Change this line to <jsp-config development="true"/>

Answer (score 3):

**Follow this procedure to enable hot deployment enable in JBOSS**

It will work on JBoos AS 7.0.1 and should work on other versions with slight changes

1. Go to JBoss administrative panel (by default localhost:9990)
2. Now in profile settings open Core - Deployment Scanners
3. Turn on Autodeploy-Exploded (set to true)
4. You can set scanner time (by default 5000 ms) to appropriate as
   according to you your (I prefer to set 2000, for more fast incremental
   publishing when I make changes in projects)

**That it.**

Now JBoss make HOT deploy for almost all kind of files

Comment: but where i found files that i can save,update and see a changed live in web application?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're looking for something like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/). For those who haven't had the chance to hear about it, it's a magic tool made to get rid of such annoying redeploys after every modification made in your source files.

As you're using Netbeans IDE, this a dedicated [tuto](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/remoting/netbeans.html) explaining how to set up JRebel.

Comment: But this tool is not for free. I lookaing a free solution.

Comment: Indeed it is free if it's used for non commercial purpose.

`Please visit my.jrebel.com to get your free social JRebel license.`

Quoted from [zeroturnaround](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/jrebel-social-tutorial/) site.

Comment: Is it? -Its just 14 days free trial :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. My solution is to run the program on debug mode without editing config file. Once you are done, you can see the result without restarting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running JBoss EAP 7.x, add the following to your standalone XML:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:7.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other">
    ...
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config development="true" />
        <websockets />
    </servlet-container>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the app as exploded (project.war folder), add in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.weld.development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Copy class/jsp/etc, 
update the web.xml time stamp every-time you deploy(append blank line):

```
set PRJ_HOME=C:\Temp2\MyProject\src\main\webapp
set PRJ_CLSS_HOME=%PRJ_HOME%\WEB-INF\classes\com\myProject

set JBOSS_HOME= C:\Java\jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6\server\default\deploy\MyProject.war
set JBOSS_CLSS_HOME= %JBOSS_HOME%\WEB-INF\classes\com\myProject

copy %PRJ_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\ProfileAction.class %JBOSS_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\ProfileAction.class
copy %PRJ_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\AjaxAction.class %JBOSS_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\AjaxAction.class

ECHO.>>%JBOSS_HOME%\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using JBOSS AS 7.2

in http://127.0.0.1:9990/console/index.html#deployment-scanner

Configuration
⇒
Subsystems⇒
Subsystem
⇒
Deployment Scanners

Click on Edit, turn "Auto Deploy Exploded" to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to JBoss see the deployments folder each ten seconds

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
scan-interval="10000"/>
</subsystem>
```