# Hot deploy of JSF pages in NetBeans to JBoss standalone

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jboss, web-deployment

## Background

Here's the set up:

- Multi-developer environment using Subversion
- NetBeans 8.0.2
- JDK 1.7
- Java EE6
- JBoss 6.2 EAP running standalone

We may not change the tools; we may use neither Maven nor JRebel. Hardware upgrades are also not in scope.

### Code Organisation

The source code, including web-related files, are checked out into:

```
C:\Apps\07-Work\Project\Project-Admin\Project-Admin-User-war\
```

This directory includes a common development structure (bold are checked out from the repository):

- build - compiled files
- dist - .war file
- **nbproject** - project files
- **src** - Java source code
- **web** - JSF pages, WEB-INF directory, CSS files, etc.
- **build.xml** - Ant script

## JBoss Installation

The web application server is installed into:

```
C:\Apps\04-Tools\jboss-eap-6.2
```

## Problem

The **develop - deploy - test** cycle is painfully slow. It can take upwards of 30 seconds to test a single change to a web page. Here's the current flow:

1. Edit file in NetBeans.
2. Save file.
3. <kbd>Shift+F11</kbd> (**Run >> Clean and Build**).
4. Switch to browser tab (http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#deployments).
5. Click **Replace**.
6. Click **Choose File**.
7. Select **Project-Admin-User-war.war** file.
8. Click **Open**.
9. Click **Next**.
10. Click **Save**.
11. Switch to browser tab (http://localhost:8080/admin/users/).
12. <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page.

The build (step 3) takes about 26 seconds; manual deployment adds to that.

Here's the ideal development cycle:

1. Change a JSF page in NetBeans (note: this is a file checked out from repository).
2. Save the JSF page.
3. <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to a browser window.
4. <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page.

It isn't as important to have hot deploy on Java source changes, as code development time tends to take much longer than simple web page layout changes.

Editing the [exploded contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28044749/59087) would mean developers are no longer editing files checked out from the repository and would therefore incur additional steps, or scripts, or possible loss of work.

Others have suggested the **Deploy on save** feature, which is [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34084265/59087):

[image: Run Project Properties]

Another suggestion (as per the screen shot) is to run the application in debug mode, but selecting **Debug >> Project** (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) didn't show page updates after changes.

## Question

Is hot deploy of JSF pages possible using the given tools and constraints? If so, what are the exact steps required to achieve the ideal development cycle?

## Standalone Configuration

The [README.txt](http://pastebin.com/raw/ujBEEkP6) file shows that it is possible to "live deploy" content:

> H) Manual mode only: Live replace portions of currently deployed unzipped   content without redeploying:

```
cp -r target/example.war/foo.html $AS/standalone/deployments/example.war
```

Where the `cp` command on Windows translates to:

```
xcopy /e /s /y src dest
```

This leads to:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Change directory: `cd C:\Apps\04-Tools\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments`
3. Create skipdeploy to prevent deployment while copying is in progress: `type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.skipdeploy`
4. Copy files to create a directory containing the files that have changed:
   `xcopy /i /y /e /s C:\Apps\07-Work\Project\Project-Admin\Project-Admin-User-war\web Project-Admin-User-war.war`

Next:

1. Delete skipdeploy: `rm Project-Admin-User-war.war.skipdeploy`
2. Create dodeploy: `type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.dodeploy`
3. Return to the browser.
4. Press F5 to refresh.

The result is that a resource bundle has gone missing:

[image: Missing Resource Bundle]

## Related

- [Is it possible to deploy an exploded war file (unzipped war) in JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368629/is-it-possible-to-deploy-an-exploded-war-file-unzipped-war-in-jboss-as-7)
- [How can I get JBoss to explode a deployed WAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487363/how-can-i-get-jboss-to-explode-a-deployed-war-file)
- [Jboss step by step set hot deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044429/jboss-step-by-step-set-hot-deploy/28044749#28044749)
- https://jasonmarley.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/how-to-deploy-exploded-archives-jboss-eap-6/

Comment: Would you accept `buy the fastest development computers available` as an answer?

Comment: Why is step 3 needed? Does't save automatically copy it? even in non-debug mode? did you check? Did you configure your jsf app to run in development mode?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Save won't automatically copy it -- NetBeans doesn't know where JBoss keeps its WAR files, nor does NetBeans know whether JBoss is automatically exploding WAR files. NetBeans can be configured (as mjn's answer) to automatically deploy to JBoss, but that is only a partial solution. The solution that should take the shortest time is a straight copy to update the WAR file without either a rebuild or a redeploy. Whether the copy happens directly or indirectly (through the `deployments` directory) is now the crux of cracking this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

Achieving hot deploy using JBoss 6.2 EAP running in standalone mode is accomplished in three parts: configuration, exploding, and hot deployment.

## Configuration

Ensure that a [deployment scanner](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Deployment+Scanner+configuration) is configured as shown:

[image: Deployment Scanner Settings]

Ensure the web subsystem and system properties are configured:

1. Stop JBoss.
2. Edit `%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`.
3. Immediately after `</extensions>` (before `<management>`),  disable caching:

   ```
   <system-properties>
     <property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>
     <property name="org.jboss.as.web.deployment.DELETE_WORK_DIR_ONCONTEXTDESTROY" value="true"/>
   </system-properties>
   ```
4. Find the web subsystem (e.g., `xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web...`).
5. Append the following element:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
   </configuration>
   ```
6. Save the file.
7. Start JBoss.

## Exploding

Exploding requires extracting the full contents of a WAR file with contents that will be deployed in the (very near) future.

1. Clean and build the application (<kbd>Shift+F11</kbd> in NetBeans).
2. Change to the JBoss standalone deployments directory.
3. Create a **skip deploy** file.
4. Create the WAR directory.
5. Extract the WAR file.
6. Delete the **skip deploy** file.
7. Create the **do deploy** file.

This resembles the following (on Windows platforms; substitute paths for %JBOSS_HOME% and %PROJECT_HOME% as required):

```
cd %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments
type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.skipdeploy
mkdir Project-Admin-User-war.war
cd Project-Admin-User-war.war
jar -xvf %PROJECT_HOME%\dist\Project-Admin-User-war.war
cd ..
del *skipdeploy
type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.dodeploy
```

## Hot Deployment

Create a batch file that contains the following:

```
cd %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\deployments
type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.skipdeploy
xcopy /i /y /e /s %PROJECT_HOME%\web Project-Admin-User-war.war
del *skipdeploy
type nul >> Project-Admin-User-war.war.dodeploy
```

## Web Development

The ideal development cycle has almost been achieved:

1. Edit file in NetBeans.
2. Save file.
3. Run batch file.
4. <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to browser.
5. <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh.

Ant has an [OnSaveTask](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2/org/netbeans/spi/editor/document/OnSaveTask.Factory.html) that can likely be coerced to run the batch, or even substitute for the batch file completely. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of a Ant script change from 2009 found on http://wiki.netbeans.org. Maybe it is useful still.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/TaT_DeployOnBuildUsingJBoss

And another script solution:

[How to setup JBoss server with Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557940/how-to-setup-jboss-server-with-netbeans/13372389#13372389)

Comment: @DaveJarvis well, within the given constraints (`We may not change the tools; we may use neither Maven nor JRebel`) I would say this is the best I could do (and even free). I will come back if I need a job ;)